# How can I get multirow / stacked tabs in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions

Since Firefox is planning on deprecating the vast majority of their add-ons with Firefox 57 (migrating to an incompatible/breaking-change Web Extensions API), is it possible to get Google Chrome to do things like TabMixPlus & Ubiquity was able to?

For example: Multi-row tabs (when too many tabs for one row, moves to the next row), setting tab min & max width, switching to a tab by querying all active tabs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, for most of these functions. Basically, Chrome doesn't let add-on developers manipulate the tab windows/window area like Firefox did. At one time, Google had an experimental feature which allowed "Stacked Tabs", but no longer.

Check the full API doc to see if this ever changes:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs

In the meantime, I've found the only somewhat acceptable alternative to be the **Tabli** extension.

With Tabli, I can query & select an existing tab in any Chrome window by calling `CTRL+.` . This mostly fills the gap for me - allows me to quickly find & bring an existing tab into focus without having to use the mouse/search manually.

Answer (score 0):

But Firefox still (69) supports multiraw tabs with [Izheil's scripts](https://github.com/Izheil/Quantum-Nox-Firefox-Dark-Full-Theme/tree/master/Multirow%20and%20other%20functions/Multirow%20tabs)